# What to use instead of templated virtual method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this example :

```
class Entity
{
    float mX;
    float mY;
    string mName;
    // other attributes
public:
    void setPosX(float x);
    void setPosY(float y);
    void setName(string name);
    // other setters

    template<typename T>
    virtual void setAttributeValue(string param, T value)
    {
        if(param == "x")
            setX(value);
        else if(param == "y")
            setY(value);
        else if(param == "name")
            setName(value);
        // ...
    }
};

class SpecialEntity : public Entity
{
    int specialAttr;
    // other special attributes
public:
    void setSpecialAttr(int val);
    // other setters

    template<typename T>
    virtual void setAttributeValue(string param, T value)
    {
        Entity::setAttributeValue(param, value);

        if(param == "specialAttr")
            setSpecialAttr(value);
        // ...
    }
};
```

This will not compile as templated virtual methods are not allowed.

I need this in my editor app, that has a Property Grid Control, depending on the name of the property in that control, I need to call a method from Entity class or an inherited class of Entity to set an attribute value.

What is the best way to acheive this.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a template here. Certainly `setX` and `setY` (which you don't show) aren't templated, right?

Comment: make T a string, then use two strings or a string pair as input, then parse the string in the function.

Comment: If you are using Qt and QObject, this function could (almost) be fully automated.

Comment: 'T' can be of any type, like int, float, string, Vector etc ...

Comment: @MarkRansom as I said, T can be a complexe type such as vector, matrix, structs

Comment: Then how do you want your compiler to cast a vector to float, for setX?

Comment: That template function would not compile even if it wasn't virtual, as there is no `setName` function taking a `float`.

Comment: Basically, what you're trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: You are trying to use polymorphism in a place where you know the specific type and where you need to know the specific type. That makes this a non-polymorphic problem. Its just not the right tool for the job. I would have specific *getters* and *setters* for your special types as per @pm100 answer. Instead of calling `setAttributeValue()` with the name of the function you want to call, just call that function.

Comment: @Galik I think I recognize the pattern - they want a generic base class method that can set any attribute on any subclass, no matter what the type of that attribute. C++ templates simply aren't powerful enough to solve that problem.

Comment: @Galik yes that's exactely what I want, I'm using wxWidgets library and it has a wxAny class just like the boost's one, and it's working as expected.

Comment: If the caller gets the type wrong, do you care what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a template function like that, virtual or otherwise. All the function calls within each version of your template function have to compile even if you never intend to call them.

All that happens with template functions is a copy of the function is stamped out with `T` replaced with each type as needed. If you do it by hand it is easy to see that it will not compile. In this case there is no `setX` taking a `string` and no `setName` taking a `float`:

```
class Entity
{
    float mX;
    std::string mName;
public:
    void setX(float x){ mX = x; }
    void setName(std::string name){ mName = name; }

    void setAttributeValue(std::string param, float value)
    {
        if(param == "x")
            setX(value);
        else if(param == "name")
            setName(value);  // Error!
    }
    void setAttributeValue(std::string param, std::string value)
    {
        if(param == "x")
            setX(value);  // Error!
        else if(param == "name")
            setName(value);
    }    
};
```

I suggest you make `setAttributeValue` virtual and non-templated and pass in a type that can be converted to any type. Perhaps a `string`,  `boost::any` or `boost::variant`.

If you can't use `boost::any` or `boost::variant` you could create your own `Value` interface to pass in:

```
struct Value {
  virtual float getFloat() const = 0;
  virtual std::string getString() const = 0;
  virtual int getInt() const = 0;
};

struct ValueBase : Value {
  float getFloat() const override { throw std::runtime_error("Not float"); }
  std::string getString() const override { throw std::runtime_error("Not string"); }    
  int getInt() const override { throw std::runtime_error("Not int"); }
};

struct FloatValue : ValueBase {
  float value;
  FloatValue(float value) : value(value){}
  float getFloat() const override { return value; }
};

struct StringValue : ValueBase {
  std::string value;
  StringValue(std::string value) : value(value){}
  std::string getString() const override { return value; }
};

struct IntValue : ValueBase {
  int value;
  IntValue(int value) : value(value){}
  int getInt() const override { return value; }
};

class Entity {
    float mX;
    float mY;
    std::string mName;
public:
    void setX(float x);
    void setY(float y);
    void setName(std::string name);
    virtual void setAttributeValue(std::string param, const Value& value) {
        if(param == "x")
            setX(value.getFloat());
        else if(param == "y")
            setY(value.getFloat());
        else if(param == "name")
            setName(value.getString());
    }
};

class SpecialEntity : public Entity {
    int specialAttr;
public:
    void setSpecialAttr(int val);
    void setAttributeValue(std::string param, const Value& value) override {
        Entity::setAttributeValue(param, value);
        if(param == "specialAttr")
            setSpecialAttr(value.getInt());
    }
};
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3tlxmr5acS43ZNrQ).

Comment: Nice solution. Then, I need to create a class that inherits from ValueBase for each type I want to use.

Answer (score 2):

When I've had to do this, one of the options I've used is to pass a `boost::any` rather than a `T`.

```
virtual void setAttributeValue(string param, boost::any value)
{
    if(param == "x")
        setX(boost::any_cast<int>(value));
    else if(param == "y")
        setY(boost::any_cast<int>(value));
    else if(param == "name")
        setName(boost::any_cast<std::string>(value));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't use boost nor Qt, if it's possible can you give a simple implementation of a boost::any class

Comment: this is a good answer but I dont like the design idea. A c++ class is a strong non reflective thing not a javascript object that can just have arbitrary junk thrust at it

Comment: @pm100 I don't disagree. But sometimes its a path you're forced down. The particular cases where I've had to use it or something similar was when bridging between C++ and more "dynamic"/less typesafe languages.

Comment: @rlbond - you can certainly use a union - but wrap it in a class so that you can use a discriminated union - otherwise you very quickly end up with nasty bugs due to accidentally invoking undefined behaviour. But if you use a union you need to know all your types up-front. (Of course boost also provides helper classes to make this less painful, think its called `boost::variant`)

Comment: @Merabtene - even if you cant use boost, you can certainly read its code for inspiration. `boost::any` is a relatively simple class - it's just got quite a few clever bits for working around bad compilers.... if you know your compiler is going to be relatively recent you can probably make it even shorter.

Comment: I'm using wxWidgets library and it seems it contains a class named wxAny that do the same thing as boost::any.

Answer (score 1):

do it the old fashioned way

```
setX(int)
setY(float)
setZ(string)
```

much safer (the compiler will spot errors) and faster

Comment: Can't, I use polymorphism, I have an array of Entity*, and I need to set an attribute value depending of a string (the name of the property on the GUI)

Comment: @Merabtene That doesn't make much sense. Why not post realistic code?

Comment: @juanchopanza I know my code is a mess, but the problem I want to solve does make a sense

Comment: @Merabtene You're not using polymorphism, you have a stack of `if() else if()` statements checking the type. That is exactly what polymorphism was designed to avoid.

Comment: @Galik I'm speaking about the app, when I call setAttributeValue on an Entity*, the GUI provides a onPropertyChanger with its name and new value, I need to set the attribute value of Entity (or a derived class) related to the changer property

Comment: @Merabtene What type is the value? Is it always a string?

Comment: @Merabtene So do you have to do `if()` on the property name in order to know what type to extract? If so, you may as well use those `if()` statements to figure out the type of the object that needs  updatng and calling the specific *getter* or *setter* as per this answer.

Comment: @Merabtene You still missed the important point. When you have code template `T` to a `vector`, or something else, the compiler doesn't what `param` is, so it need to generate code for all branches, for type `T`. Then, as mention by me and others a lot of times already, if any of your setters doesn't support this `T`, compilation would fail. E.g. if you call it with `setAttributeValue("name", "Foo")`, it just won't compile, virtual or not.

Comment: then put the big if statement outside the class no in it - you cant pretend that c++ is javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use the curiously recurring template pattern, a polymorphic base class, some tagging and a polymorphic value class to achieve your desired functionality

First we need a polymorphic value type:

```
struct value{ virtual ~value(){} };

struct text_value: public value{ text_value(const std::string &str_): str(str_){} std::string str; };
struct int_value: public value{ int_value(int i_): i(i_){} int i; };

auto make_value(const std::string &str){ return text_value{str}; }
auto make_value(int i){ return int_value{i}; }
```

then our static (CRTP) and dynamic polymorphisms:

```
enum class entity_tag{
    text
};

class entity{
    public:
        entity(entity_tag tag_): tag(tag_){}
        virtual ~entity(){}

        entity_tag tag;
};

template<typename Entity>
class entity_base: entity{
    public:
        entity_base(): entity(this->get_tag()){}

        template<typename T>
        void set_value(const std::string &param, T &&val){
            reinterpret_cast<Entity*>(this)->set_value_impl(param, std::forward<T>(val));
        }

        static entity_tag get_tag(){
            return Entity::get_tag_impl();
        }
};
```

Then we can start defining some classes that implement our interface! (`set_value_impl` and `get_tag_impl`)

```
class text_entity: public entity_base<text_entity>{
    protected:
        std::string font = "times new roman";
        int font_size = 10;
        std::string text = "";

        void set_text(value &&v){
            auto tv = dynamic_cast<text_value&&>(v);
            text = std::move(tv.str);
        }

        void set_font(value &&v){
            auto tv = dynamic_cast<text_value&&>(v);
            font = std::move(tv.str);
        }

        void set_font_size(value &&v){
            auto iv = dynamic_cast<int_value&&>(v);
            font_size = iv.i;
        }

    public:
        static entity_tag get_tag_impl(){ return entity_tag::text; }

        template<typename T>
        void set_value_impl(const std::string &str, T &&val){
            auto v = make_value(val);

            if(str == "text")
                set_text(std::move(v));
            else if(str == "font")
                set_font(std::move(v));
            else if(str == "font_size")
                set_font_size(std::move(v));
            else
                throw "invalid parameter"; 
        }
};
```

It's as easy as 1, 2, 3!

You can use it the same way you wanted to in your question:

```
int main(){
    text_entity text;
    text.set_value("font", "comic sans");
    text.set_value("font_size", 24);
    text.set_value("text", "Comic sans sucks");
}
```

It also won't let you try to assign e.g. a `float` to `"font"` because there is not value type for `float`. If there were, it would throw an exception within `set_font`.

You could define the `value` subclasses within each `entity` subclass so that the compiler will always complain if a value is given that won't be possible for any given parameter.

Also you can store the entities inside of a container with other entity types:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<entity*> entities;
    text_entity text0;
    text_entity text1;
    pic_entity pic0;
    slider_entity slider0;
    entities.push_back(&text0);
    entities.push_back(&text1);
    entities.push_back(&pic0);
    entities.push_back(&slider0);
}
```

But to access the `set_value` function of each `entity` you will need to have a look at the `tag` variable associated with each variable:

```
template<typename T>
void set_value_of_text(entity *e, const std::string &param, T &&t){
    if(e->tag != entity_tag::text)
        throw "entity is not a text entity";

    dynamic_cast<text_entity*>(e)->set_value(param, std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

You could use something other than an `enum class` for the `tag` type to make it easier for future additions of entity types

Comment: `dynamic_cast<text_entity*>(e)` will return NULL if `e` is not a `text_entity`. So why not use that instead of having any need for a tag?

Comment: If your value types are going to just contain a member of that type why not `template<typename T> class value_impl : public value { T v; ... }` and `template<typename T> value_impl<T> make_value(T v) { return value_impl<T>(v); }` ?

Comment: I like your second point (y) the first point doesn't stand though, because my use of the tag was just a bad example. A better use would be a switch statement. That would be *much* faster than testing whether a `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr`. Of course, it's always an alternative though.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I take it back, a `template value_impl` doesn't work in this case. If I wrote that, then when `set_value` was called with a string constant as it's second value more work would have to be done for the compiler to detect that and construct an `std::string`. It's much easier to just have a single case for strings.